# apostrophe issue with ajax post to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am posting data with jquery ajax to php but if input has `'` inside, data wont be posted. I tried `encodeURIComponent` but wont work.

any idea on this ?

thanks

EDIT: 
my code

```
var name = $("input#name_add").val();
         name = encodeURIComponent(name);

$.post("function.php", { name: name }, function(data) {

                               //codes
                });



$query = "UPDATE `table` SET name = '" . stripslashes($_POST['name']) . "' WHERE ID = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result){
print "ok";

}
```

Comment: Can we have client/server code code snippets?

Comment: When you use the post method why do you encode the string? That should only be necessary if you use get.

Comment: if input has & % chars, there happened some problems thats why i am encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the magic quotes setting on your server with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. If it's on you need to `strip_slashes()` before using using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Check the [get_magic_quotes_gpc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) documentation for an example.

Comment: damn, i cant find anything about escaping apostrophes in javascript

Answer (score 4):

encodeURIComponent does not encode apostrophe, try this:

```
encodeURIComponent(str).replace("'", "%27");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `magic_quotes_gpc` is off why are you stripping slashes in your query?

Try:

```
$query = "UPDATE `table` SET name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "' WHERE ID = '$id'";
```

If you're using POST you shouldn't need to escape the data before passing it, but by using stripslashes in your code for the mysql you're gonna cause problems with any apostrophes as then your sql won't be escaped.

Comment: "If you're using POST you shouldn't need to escape the data before passing it" but special chars break ajax if i didnt escape in javascript

Comment: @Ahmet vardar Is that all of your code? You're using `encodeURIComponent` in your js but stripping slashes in the php. `encodeURIComponent` encodes data with hex codes not slashes, so why are you stripping slashes. By stripping slashes there you're passing non escaped data to mysql which will cause it to break anyway when you use apostrophes let alone the mysql injection problems.

Comment: ok i replaced strip slash with mysql_real_escape_string, and in js i made this as temp. solution name=name.replace("'"," ");

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved it for me. Since the JavaScript encodeURIComponent() function does not encode apostrophes to %27, I did it myself using my own replaceAll() function.

**JS Snippet:**

```
name = encodeURIComponent(name.replaceAll("'", '%27'));
```

This is the replaceAll() function in my utilities **JS file**:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(f, r, no_escape) {
    var rexp = new RegExp(Util.EscapeRegExp(f), 'g');
    if (no_escape) { rexp = new RegExp(f, 'g'); }
    return this.replace(rexp, r);
};
```

For my purposes, I needed the apostrophe to not be %27 anymore, and the PHP function urldecode() does not do apostrophes either, so I used str_replace() to take care of that.

**PHP Snippet**:

```
$name = str_replace('%27', "'", urldecode($_POST['name'] ) );
```